# How to avoid defining single element array in java lambda expression

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have written code segment which fetches a single element from list matching some condition. Is there any way I could replace single element array with the object of the same type?

```
final PromoSlotSize[] slot = new PromoSlotSize[1];
promoSlotSizeList.stream()
    .filter(promoSlotSize -> promoSlotSize.getOfferSet().equals(Constants.HVT_RATE_OFFER_SET))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(p-> slot[0] =p);
```

Comment: What is `PromoSlotSize` and `promoSlotSizeList`!!

Comment: why array of 1 element ? And not just one element ?

Comment: @azro try it... might complain about `final` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your approach seems to be such overkill. Note that initializing an array with

```
final PromoSlotSize[] slot = new PromoSlotSize[1];
```

Makes the first and only element `slot[0] = null` bu default. Thus, you can make the Stream-API return the first found object `PromoSlotSize` or `null` again using [`Optional::orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-):

```
slot[0] = promoSlotSizeList.stream()
              .filter(i-> i.getOfferSet().equals(Constants.HVT_RATE_OFFER_SET))
              .findFirst()
              .orElse(null);
```

---

As *@YCF_L* says: Do you recognize that the Stream returns an object which might be used directly instead of creating an array of one element? If you don't need an array as input to another method/class, do the following :

```
PromoSlotSize slot = promoSlotSizeList.stream()
          .filter(i-> i.getOfferSet().equals(Constants.HVT_RATE_OFFER_SET))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Note that if you don't care which instance you get (in cases where there are multiple matches to the `filter()` lambda), `.findAny()` is more efficient than `findFirst()`. `findFirst()` processes the entire stream, then returns the first one found, where as `findAny()` will bail out and return as soon as it finds a matching element, discarding the rest of the stream.

Comment: @KevinSwan any documentation to back this up?

Comment: https://blog.codefx.org/java/stream-findfirst-findany-reduce/ "Both methods return an arbitrary element from the stream – unless the stream has an encounter order, in which case findFirst() returns the first element."

Comment: @KevinSwan read that blog again and show us where it says that `findFirst` will process the entire stream?

Comment: If an encounter order is specified, then it must process the entire stream. How could it return the "first" one, after sorting, if it hasn't examined the entire list? How could it be sure that there does not exist another element later in the list that would precede the current "first" candidate? `findAny()` allows implementations to perform short circuit evaluation and terminate as soon as it finds a matching element, making it non-deterministic. It's moot here, as the OP's example doesn't specify an encounter order, but it's an important distinction to be aware of.

Comment: @KevinSwan *How could it return the "first" one, after sorting* - where have you seen sorted here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177734/discussion-between-kevin-swan-and-eugene).

Answer (score 2):

The code uses a trick, as only (effectively) final variables may be used from outside in the lambda. Hence a final array where the first element can be set.
In effect it uses imperative style coding, with a loop and a result.

However the following is far better.

```
Optional<PromoSlotSize> slot = promoSlotSizeList.stream()
                        .filter(i -> i.getOfferSet().equals(Constants.HVT_RATE_OFFER_SET))
                        .findAny();

slot.ifPresent(sl -> System.out.println("Slot present: " + sl));
```

As it can be parallelized, and the two attributes: boolean found + Slot result are incorporated in one Optional.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a `copy` from method on `PromoSlotSize` class. That method should take and argument of `PromoSlotSize` object and populate it self with given PromoSlotSize data

```
final PromoSlotSize slot = new PromoSlotSize();
promoSlotSizeList.stream()
            .filter(promoSlotSize -> promoSlotSize.getOfferSet().equals(Constants.HVT_RATE_OFFER_SET))
            .findFirst().ifPresent(p-> slot.copy(p));
```

Assuming PromoSlotSize is a class you wrote, this should allow you to get rid of single element arrays.